# How do I find more throat sprays?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I didn't know that the item disappeared after a single use, now I've wasted it on a random battle.  How do I get another one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After defeating the Champion, you can buy more in the [Battle Tower](https://www.serebii.net/pokearth/galar/battletower.shtml) for 10 BP.

Answer (score 9):

As with most consumable battle items, like Focus Sash and Luminous Moss, Throat Sprays can be bought at the Battle Tower for Battle Points.